# Add a build number to TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a lot of legacy Delphi 5 & 6 Code.  We want to test this code using the new Microsoft Test Manager (part of VS2010)

To effectively track your testing using this tool you need to use build numbers.  To get Delphi 5 or 6 building in TFS Build 2010 is a huge task.  One that I am not sure I want to take on.

Is there a way I can just insert my build numbers in to tfs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build numbers are stored in a global list which the build process adds to each time it runs.  You can download the global list from TFS, edit it and then republish the updated version back up to the server.

I'd suggest using the TFS 2010 Power Tools to do it ([link](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/3e8c9b68-6e39-4577-b9b7-78489b5cb1da))